# Is there something missing in the code that it doesn't fill up the other info

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a server info command but my code doesn't fill up the other information, I have enabled both intents from discord applications, and in the code, is there somethings wrong with the code? please help!

```
      @commands.command(name='server', aliases=["serverinfo"], no_pm=True)
        async def _server(self, ctx):
            guild = ctx.message.guild
            online = len([m.status for m in guild.members
                          if m.status == discord.Status.online or
                          m.status == discord.Status.idle])
            total_users = len(guild.members)
            total_bots = len([member for member in guild.members if member.bot == True])
            total_humans = total_users - total_bots
            text_channels = len(ctx.guild.text_channels)
            voice_channels = len(ctx.guild.voice_channels)
            passed = (ctx.message.created_at - guild.created_at).days
            created_at = ("Since {}. Over {} days ago."
                          "".format(guild.created_at.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M"),
                                    passed))
    
            embed = discord.Embed(description=created_at, colour=discord.Colour.blue())
            embed.add_field(name="Region", value=str(guild.region))
            embed.add_field(name="Users", value="{}/{}".format(online, total_users))
            embed.add_field(name="Humans", value=total_humans)
            embed.add_field(name="Bots", value=total_bots)
            embed.add_field(name="Text Channels", value=text_channels)
            embed.add_field(name="Voice Channels", value=voice_channels)
            embed.add_field(name="Roles", value=len(guild.roles))
            embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=str(guild.owner))
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Guild ID:{str(guild.id)}",icon_url= 'https://i.imgur.com/brUOIbi.gif')
    
            if guild.icon_url:
                embed.set_author(name=guild.name, url=guild.icon_url, icon_url= 'https://i.imgur.com/brUOIbi.gif')
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=guild.icon_url)
            else:
                embed.set_author(name=guild.name,icon_url= 'https://i.imgur.com/brUOIbi.gif')
    
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Am I missing something in the code? I currently have this in cogs, I think something is wrong that it is like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEDUc.png

It seems that it would not list the related information. (currently new in coding)

Comment: @Hevlastka need halp again welpy im still learning : )

Comment: Have you enabled intents? If yes - which?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński yes intents are enabled and also enabled in the dev portal

Comment: By the way, `== True` is not needed in an `if` statement. `if member.bot == True` can just be `if member.bot`.

Comment: On a more related note, please do not use discord.py as an early project in coding. Many people have made this exact mistake before; please don't make it yourself.